# Logic App HTTP GET request : I put 2 app id & secret but i got output for one app . Can someone help me out

Tags: azure, logic, power-automate

[image]

Can someone help me out ......!

Comment: Absolutely impossible to help.  Add waaaaaaay more detail and maybe we have a chance.

Comment: I have a logic app , i got a notification if my application going to expired but i want it send an email to application owner first then the tenant owner 
that i can not do that

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send mail to application owner and tenant owner, you can use send email action in logic app.

- Created logic app as shown below,
  [image]
- Use condition action, you can check expiry date with current time using expression.
- If it is successful it will go to true block. In that block you can add send email action to send mail to app owner first then tenant owner.
  [image]
- Also if you are not getting output for one app, try to check if app id and secret are properly configured in logic app get request. Also check the tenant value of the app which you are not able to get output.
  Reference [link](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/core-infrastructure-and-security/use-azure-logic-apps-to-notify-of-pending-aad-application-client/ba-p/3014603)